# Accessing Android Kernel methods from an app on Android smartphone

Tags: android, gpio, android-kernel

I have a USB that gives access GPIO pins. In my understanding the pins can be controlled with android kernel method `static int SetGpo(struct usbnet * dev, u32 Gpo, u32 State);` ([Github](https://github.com/sktjdgns1189/android_kernel_samsung_SHW-M190S/blob/master/drivers/misc/smsc9500/smsc9500.c)). I'm wondering how could I access this method from an app and control the pins?

I don't have experience in things under the android app layer so it's hard for me to know where to start. Some sources I found mentioned that I need a rooted device.